# Task Sheduler: How to run batch file through cmd instead of taskeng.exe?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-xp, scheduled-tasks

I wrote a simple script:

```
cd C:\TESTS\example
call git pull
cd C:\TESTS\example\AutoApp\bin\debug
start AutoApp.exe
```

I created daily task in sheduler and when task running it open taskeng.exe. That "command line" do not have any git/cmd command wich I use in script. And my application and git pull do not work.

If I open batch file by click on it, it works fine(git pull done and app run done) and run through cmd.

After firs option of anwser task is running all time.

**After second option of anwser.**

[image: Afret second option of anwser]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: what is `git` here? Is it an application or another batch file? where is it stored? C:\TESTS\example?

Comment: I pull repo in example folder with dlls for AutoApp.exe also in this repo is script, but i do not change script never.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the command line used in Task Scheduler to call cmd.exe to launch the batch file instead:

```
cmd /c "YourBatchFile.bat"
```

Or

```
%comspec% /c "YourBatchFile.bat"
```

Comment: Where I can change it?

Comment: In the Task Scheduler dialog (where you set up the scheduled task to run), of course. Where else? (The same place you "created daily task in scheduler".)

Comment: I can "browse" for program then "Add arguments(optional)" and "Start in(optional)"

Comment: Right. Now, after you "browse for program" and choose your batch file, edit that box (where your batch file appears) and add what I told you in front of the name of your batch file.

Comment: task is running and so on...nothing else. In history I have last command: "Created Task Process". Notinhg is happen.

Comment: I have no idea what you've done, based on the images you've posted. Whatever that is right after `C:\Windows\System32>` is clearly not `cmd /c` or the name of a batch file, and it's causing the first `cd` to fail. I don't know why `git` isn't being called, but I'd suspect it's not on your PATH. The call to `start AutoApp` is failing because the `cd` before it isn't finding the folder, and therefore the command is failing, and because of that `AutoApp.exe` isn't found in the folder you're currently in (C:\Windows\System32). None of that has anything to do with my answer here.